# Restore a schema/table from a dump file created with --format=c

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to restore a schema from a database backup made with pg_dump using the following options:

```
pg_dump.exe --file "mydb.backup" --host "localhost" --port "5432" --username "postgres"
--no-password --verbose --role "postgres" --format=c --blobs --compress "9"
--encoding "UTF8" "mydb"
```

And restore only one table from another schema?

Comment: See [pg_restore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html) docs: `-n schema Restore only objects that are in the named schema. Multiple schemas may be specified with multiple -n switches. This can be combined with the -t option to restore just a specific table.` and `-t table Restore definition and/or data of only the named table`,

Comment: Adrian, I have tried with: pg_restore -U postgres -d tmp -c -n mySchema 'path2\db.backup', but I get an error: pg_restore: error: failed to open input file "'path2\db.backup'": Invalid argument.

Comment: 1) Is `path2\db.backup` actually the full path to the file? 2) Try with `/` in the path.

Comment: This is not related to software development. It is a question of locating and naming a file on the operating system.

Comment: Thank you Adrian. The problem with file access is now solved: it is not possible to write the file name between ' '. Then, when running pg_restore it required me to create the schema first to perform the restore; I didn't know this either, I was trying to do the restore of the schema without having previously created it.